# Error by Graphql Subscription with Error: "Error during subscription handshake"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I try to create a chat application with graphql. For that I need a subscription. But when I try to implement the subscription, I always get the error: "Error during subscription handshake"

I'm using AWS Appsync as the server and the aws-amplify appolo provider as the client.

This is my code for the subscription.

```
export default graphql(gql(queryChatsByUserConversatioID), {
  options: (props) => ({
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    variables: {
      UserConversationID: "Test"
    }
  }),
  props: props => ({
    chats: props.data.queryChatsByUserConversatioID
      ? props.data.queryChatsByUserConversatioID.items
      : [],
    data: props.data,
    subscribeToNewChats: params => {
      props.data.subscribeToMore({
        document: gql(onCreateChat),
        updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData: { data : { onCreateChat } } }) => ({
          ...prev,
          queryChatsByUserConversatioID: { __typename: 'ChatConnection', items: [onCreateChat, ...prev.queryChatsByUserConversatioID.items.filter(chat => chat.id !== onCreateChat.id)] }
        })
      })
    }
  })
})(ChatView);
```

Have any one an idea to fix this or to get a more useful error message?